# SSRS sum grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a report

```
Order               Revenue                 SUM
1                      100  
2                      200  
                                             Total=300
3                      100  
4                      400  
5                      500  
6                      200  
                                            Grand Total = 1500
```

Here I want sum of the first 2 rows and grand total in the end. What should I write in the expression cell in row group?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Running Value**.

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Revenue.Value, Sum, Nothing)
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136(v=sql.100).aspx